# How to set column width for GridBagLayout in Java

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to create a layout looks like the attached picture. It has 2 panels. The left Panel with the minimum width is 500px, resizes when JFrame is resized. The right panel has a fixed width 120px. And there is a 10px padding between them.

I tried GridBagLayout but it seems not work as expected. Please help. Thank you.

[image]

```
    JPanel leftBox;
    JPanel rightBox;
    JButton btnSave;
    JButton btnRefresh;
    JTextArea txtArea;

    leftBox = new JPanel();
    rightBox = new JPanel();

    btnSave = new JButton("Save");
    btnRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");

    txtArea = new JTextArea();
    txtArea.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 14));

    leftBox.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftBox, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    leftBox.add(txtArea);

    rightBox.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightBox, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    rightBox.add(btnSave);
    rightBox.add(btnRefresh);

    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill  = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    this.add(leftBox, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill  = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    this.add(rightBox, gbc);

    txtArea.append("-------------");
```

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - it seems to work if `gbc.weightx = 1f;` is used for the first constraint, and `0f` is used for the second. Also change `txtArea = new JTextArea();` to something like `txtArea = new JTextArea(15,20);` to suggest an initial size, and wrap it in a scroll pane for aesthetics and usability. *"a 10px padding between them"* - use the `Insets` of the `GridBagConstraints` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It works if `gbc.weightx = 1f;` is used for the first constraint, and `0f` is used for the second.
- Also change `txtArea = new JTextArea();` to something like `txtArea = new JTextArea(15,20);` to suggest an initial size.
- Wrap the text area in a scroll pane for aesthetics and usability.
- *"a 10px padding between them"* - use the `Insets` of the `GridBagConstraints` for that.

Here is how it might look after implementing those suggestions.

[image]

..and dragged wider.

[image]